# STL: pointer associative sorted container: sorting predicate template

Tags: c++, templates, stl, predicate

There is my program that illustrates predicate template that could be used as sorting predicate for STL containers instantiation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, template <typename> class comp = std::less> struct ComparePtr: public binary_function<T const *, T const *, bool> {
  bool operator()(T const *lhs, T const *rhs) const {
    comp<T> cmp;
    return (cmp(*lhs, *rhs));
  }
};

int wmain() {
  string sa[] = {"Programmer", "Tester", "Manager", "Customer"};
  set<string *, ComparePtr<string>> ssp;
  for (int i(0) ; i < sizeof sa/sizeof sa[0] ; ++i)
    ssp.insert(sa + i);

  for_each(ssp.begin(), ssp.end(), [](string *s){ cout << s->c_str() << endl; });

  return 0;
}
```

Please, focus on predicate: is it written correctly?
Is it good to instantiate `comp`? Is there a way that allows not to instantiate `comp` predicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a template template at all and not just add a simple wrapper around general binary comparators?

```
template<typename P>
struct PointerPred {
  P p;
  template<typename T>
  bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) { return p(*x, *y); }
};
```

[Boost Pointer Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) could also make this a lot easier.

Ildjarn showed how to implement your functor correctly:

```
template<template<typename> class comp = std::less>
struct ComparePtr {
  template<typename T>
  bool operator()(T const *lhs, T const *rhs) const {
    return comp<T>()(*lhs, *rhs);
  }
};
```

This way it isn't necessary to specify the type of the arguments anymore.

Edit: There used to be `std::forward` and rvalue references in my code, which made absolutely no sense.

Comment: "*Why use a template template at all*" Because it doesn't require that one spell out the type of `T`, whereas your approach does. C.f. http://ideone.com/jvTnm where all that's needed is `ComparePtr<>`, with nothing else specified.

Comment: @ildjarn Makes sense. This wasn't the case in OPs code though, so I never considered it. Can you post it as an answer? I'll remove my answer afterwards.

Comment: I'm fine with you editing your answer, no big deal either way. :-]